# Stacked inputs becoming async over time

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I have two streams going into the same remote server, from which I pull them and stack them as well as syncing them. However, after about half a minute, they are noticeably async.

This command is what I've been using so far to achieve it:

```sh
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://pulverschuppen.de:1935/leon/gopro" \
  -i "rtmp://pulverschuppen.de:1935/jake/gopro" \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART) / (TB * 1000000)'[v1sync]; [1:v]setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART) / (TB * 1000000)'[v2sync]; [v1sync]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[v1]; [v2sync]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[v2]; [v1][v2]hstack=inputs=2[stacked]" \
  -map "[stacked]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 500k \
  -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/combined
```

Any way to keep them in sync? It says a few dropped frames and some issues encoding, is that what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it always be async over time, because RTMP is TCP stream, so the network jitter causes the stream to be buffered, and the large buffer 1~3s also make it very hard to be sync.

If you want to two streams from a server to be sync, you could try some UDP based protocol, they're low latency and actually be sync.

For example, you could publish and play two streams to SRS by [SRT](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/1147) or [WebRTC](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/307), they're eventually sync. Please use Chrome for WebRTC, and FFmpeg/ffplay for SRT.

Comment: Proprietary streaming integration only allows for RTMP. Is there a way to sync them on the receiving end?

Comment: Yep, you should enable ATC time on media server like SRS, then you could use absolute timestamp on your player.